# EXWM Fails to Start on Ubuntu Based System (Linux Mint)

Tags: x-window

I'm trying to [use Emacs as my X Window manager](https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm). However, it doesn't seem to work properly. My X server did start and so did Emacs. However, I always got the error

> Warning (emacs): [EXWM] EXWM fails to start (invalid-slot-name: (# cl-slot-descriptor))

in Emacs.

I followed the instructios at https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm/wiki, here's my
~/.xinitrc file:

```
# Disable access control
xhost +SI:localuser:$USER

# Make Java applications aware this is a non-reparenting window manager.
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1

# Themes, etc
gnome-settings-daemon &

# Fallback cursor
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr

# Keyboard repeat rate
xset r rate 200 60

# Start Emacs
exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session emacs
```

and here's what I put in my init.el:

```
(require 'exwm)
(require 'exwm-config)

(exwm-config-default)
```

Here's how I started the X server:

1. After login to gnome session, press Ctrl-Alt-F1
2. Login to virtual console
3. $ xinit -display :1 -- :1 vt1

Instead of running:

```
xinit -display :1 -- :1 vt1
```

I've also tried:

```
sudo service mdm stop
xinit -- vt01
```

With the exact same results.

Comment: This is not a problem of your `.xinitrc` file. Probably the problem lies within your `init.el`, but you have not posted the full file. Try running emacs without your `init.el` and run your `exwm` initialisation lines directly from scratch buffer.

Comment: @jue There's probably no problem in .xinitrc file. My init.el has probably several thousands of lines split into 76 files. Therefore, I don't think I should post them here. But anyways, I've taken out everything except the few lines to load exwm. Still the same error.

Comment: I have the same error. Also running Linux Mint 18. Perplexed on how to resolve this. Well, I have found that removing (exwm-config-default) resolves the error but EXWM does not function properly when logging in from the login screen. (i.e. does not start fullscreen and does not manage Xwindows correctly) Did you make any progress?

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using? There's a chance your problem is caused by an outdated version of it.

Comment: still not working here.